# Dataframe task distribution basing on conditions changing during distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's consider two separate dataframes:

**DF1:**

```
ID    Name    Surname    Total_Value    [further, not important as of now booleans etc.]
1     John    Smith      1.0
2     Adam    Johnson    0.95
```

**DF2:**

```
Task_Name    Value    Person_ID
[...]        [...]    [...]
Task_132     0.08     None
```

This is a very simplified version of a problem that I have, so if that would matter in responses please let me know. What I'm trying to do is to distribute all tasks from **DF2** to a person having the least Total_Value in **DF1**. Obviously, when I assign Task#132 to Adam Johnson, he's going to have bigger Total_Value, so next task is going to be distributed to another person.

As of now, I've solved that with a terrible VBA code which basically loops through each element in **DF2** and then again loops through all **DF1** elements (up to 10 times, to find the best possible fit). When there's ~200 elements in **DF1** and 4000 elements in **DF2** it takes way too long and is simply not a good solution in case of future changes.

I do believe there's a better way to do this in Python, but I'm not sure how to go about that without using multiple loops and redefining DataFrames along the way.

EDIT: Still didn't came up with any other solution and I'm wondering if that's possible at all, considering the silence.

EDIT2: To be frank, it doesn't even need to use DataFrames. If there's any other way to do that, I can adjust.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make querying the smallest element in DF1 a lot faster if you implement it as a [Priorityqueue](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-priority-queues-in-python-83664d3178c3) for example using [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html). These data structures allow extracting the smallest element and inserting/updating an element in `O(log n)` time. You would still need to loop through the tasks in DF2, but updating would be much faster.